# Omega Sub Theme Settings Page is Blank

Tags: 7

I have recently downloaded and installed Omega 7.X-3.1 theme on my Drupal site.

I followed the handbooks instructions to create my first simple HTML5 Omega sub-theme. With the sub-theme enabled I try to navigate to /admin/appearance/settings/*themename* however I only receive a blank HTML page and a 500 error.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: instead of adding the solution to question itself, you should consider to put it as "Answer your own question". This will also remove the question from unanswered questions' queue.

Comment: I would like to however I do not have the required reputation to answer my own question.